# python ood - duplicate information between classes

Tags: python

I am trying to represent group membership with a Member class and a Guest class. The problem is that I need a Group to be able to tell me which Members are members of the group, but I also need a Member to be able to tell me which Groups it is a member of.

For instance, using the following:

```
class Member:
    MemberCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.MemberID = Member.MemberCount
        Member.MemberCount += 1

    def displayMember(self):
        print "Member ID %d" % self.MemberID
        print "Member name %s" % self.name

class Group:
    groupCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.MemberList = []
        self.groupID = Group.groupCount
        Group.groupCount += 1

    def addMember(self, Member):
        self.MemberList.append(Member)

    def displayGroup(self):
        print "Group ID %d" % self.groupID
        print "Group name %s" % self.name
        print "This group contains the following members"
        for i in self.MemberList:
            print i.name,
            print "\n"

#Create some members
member1 = Member("Tim")
member2 = Member("Bill")
member3 = Member("Jack")
member4 = Member("Julian")
member5 = Member("Alex")

#Create some groups
group1 = Group("Golf Club")
group2 = Group("Shooting Club")
group3 = Group("Swimming Club")

#Add the members to groups
group1.addMember(member1)
group1.addMember(member2)
group1.addMember(member3)

group2.addMember(member3)
group2.addMember(member4)
group2.addMember(member5)

group3.addMember(member1)
group3.addMember(member2)
group3.addMember(member5)

#Display the groups' members
group1.displayGroup()
group2.displayGroup()
group3.displayGroup()
```

I get the following output:

```
Group ID 0  
Group name Golf Club  
This group contains the following members  
Tim Bill Jack 

Group ID 1  
Group name Shooting Club  
This group contains the following members  
Jack Julian Alex 

Group ID 2  
Group name Swimming Club  
This group contains the following members  
Tim Bill Alex
```

Which  shows members in each group, but if I wanted to show groups which each member is part of then I would need to add a list to each guest which would list its groups, so it seems I would be storing the same information twice but just  in different forms.

How can I know both which members are members of a Group and also which  Groups a Member is part of without duplicating the information?

Answer (score 1):

First off, please consider using a common coding style, e.g. writing all classes with capital letter at start and all objects with small letter. The way you write code is confusing because you have objects having the same name as classes. (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for more on that)

Now to the problem. You basically have two ways of solving this:

1.
Add the group to each member in Group.addMember like

```
// Group
def addMember(self, member):
    self.memberList.append(member)
    member.groups.append(self)
```

This however has the disadvantage of very tight coupling. For garbage collection you'd have to unlink the objects. Also removing a member would require you to remove the member from the members list and to remove the group from the member's group list.

2.
Do a reverse query. Instead of asking the member which groups he is in, ask each group if the member is in it. You can do that querying in a method of the member like this:

```
// Member
def getGroups(self):
    groups = []
    for group in globalGroups:
        if self in group.MemberList:
            groups.append(group)
    return groups;
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the `getGroups()` should be placed. I don't think a member should have access to all groups, which happens when groups is a global list. But for the rest I agree

Comment: Well, you'll either have a global list of members or groups. You have to keep track of your objects in some place.

Answer (score 0):

> if I wanted to show groups which each member is part of then I would
>   need to add a list to each guest which would list its groups, so it
>   seems I would be storing the same information twice but just in
>   different forms.
>
> How can I know both which members are members of a Group and also
>   which Groups a Member is part of without duplicating the information?

What you describe is not duplicate information. It's fine to have a list per member to indicate in which groups they are in, and at the same time have a list per group to indicate which members it holds. It's not the same list, it's different information.

What you also should keep in mind is Seperation of Concerns.
You could implement a class or something that could keep track of everything, all members and all groups, so you have all your data in one place and don't need "duplicate" lists, but that wouldn't be so neat.

If you really don't want each member to have his own list of groups, you can (in your example) just make a function that loops over the groups and checks them for a certain member

```
def getGroupsForMember(member):
  groups = []
  for group in [group1, group2, group3]:
    if member in group.MemberList:
      groups.append(group.groupID)
  return groups
```